# How to retrieve data from database using linq?

Tags: sql, linq

Is this a correct way of retreiving data from database using linq?

```
var c= using db in db.c where c.id==id
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a correct way of retreiving data from database using linq?

partially yes.

It's better to write your query inside a method like this:

```
public static Product GetProduct(int id, string name)
{
    DBNameDataContext myDB = new DBNameDataContext();

    var product = from p in myDB.Products
                  where p.ID == id
                  && p.Name == name
                  select p;

    return product;
}
```

and then in your main code you can get your Product as below:

```
var product = GetProduct(5, "C# in Depth");
```

**(Sample code is in C#)**